# QAction parent menu

Tags: qt, qaction

How to get parent menu of a given QAction?
I have a QActions added to submenus.

Is there any way to know parent menu name of each action?

```
ui->action567->parent() //return MainWindow
ui->action567->parentWidget() //return MainWindow
ui->action567->menu() //return nullptr.
ui->action567->actionGroup() //return nullptr.
```

I can get parent menu this way:

```
for( QMenu * menu : ui->menuBar->findChildren< QMenu * >() )
{
    if( menu->actions().contains( ui->action567 ) )
    {
        qDebug() << menu << ui->action567 ;
        break;
    }
}
```

Does better and more native way exists?

Comment: Note that an action can be added to multiple menus, toolbars etc. So there isn’t a single parent, in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**associatedWidgets()** will return you a list of widgets this action was added to.

```
ui->action567->associatedWidgets();
```